# Why do the "float" and "double" data types add 0s to the output in C programming?

Tags: c

i am very new to programming and this is my first question on stack overflow. 
i am just learning about data types and have come across this simple example of floats and doubles. 
now, i understand what the program is doing but what i dont understand is why float and double have added so many 0s to the output.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    float number1 = 13.5;
    double number2 = 12.4;

    printf("number1 = %f\n", number1);
    printf("number2 = %lf", number2);
    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
   number1= 13.500000
   number2= 12.400000
```

now, we didnt include those 0s when we declared the value. Why do they get added to the output? 
At first i was thinking its because a float is 4 bytes of data so the zeros were to pad missing data but the number is only 8 bits long which is only 2 bytes.
i always get stuck on little details like this. thank you for you understanding.

Comment: There is a default value, but you can change if you only want one : `%.1f`.

Comment: You might also try using `%g` instead of `%f`.

Answer (score 2):

> Why do they get added to the output?

Because default precision for `%f` `printf` conversion specifier is 6, from [C11 7.21.6.1p8](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.1p8):

> f,F
>
> [...] If the precision is missing, it is taken as 6; [...]

Precision is `the number of digits to appear after the decimal-point character for a, A, e, E, f, and F conversions` from [C11 7.21.6.1p4](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.1p4). With precision = 6, `printf` will print the value with 6 digits after the comma, so with zeros.

You can specify precision yourself:

```
printf("%.1f", number1);
```

or even:

```
int precision = 1;
printf("%.*f", precision, number1);
```

You may find [cppreference printf](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) more human-readable.

Comment: ah, havent seen anything about precision yet. so if no precision is declared it defaults to a precision of 6. i will take note of this and continue reading. thank you.